# LDAP connection in Clustered instance sql job returns null results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, jobs, powershell, ldap

I wrote the following PowerShell script.  It works in jobs on my non-clustered SQL Servers (2014 version).  It works on my clustered server when I run it manually out of PowerShell (2012 version).  However, it returns null results for the users in the LDAP query when I run it as part of a SQL Agent job on this clustered server.  Any ideas?  I don't even see the server attempting an LDAP connection on the firewall that is between it and the ldap server.  It is like SQLps isn't even trying the LDAP connection.

```
#set up sql connection
$DBServer = "(<servername redacted for this post>)"
$DBName = "Aection"
$tableName = "mcommunity.phonenumbers"

$sqlConnection = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection
$sqlconnection.connectionString = "Data Source='$dbserver';Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog='$dbname'"
$sqlConnection.Open()

#get uniquenames
$command = $sqlconnection.CreateCommand()
$command.CommandText = "select distinct uniquename from PE_employee"

$users = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
$users.load($command.ExecuteReader())

#get telephone numbers for aec users from mcommunity
$auth = [System.DirectoryServices.AuthenticationTypes]::Anonymous
$domain = "LDAP://ldap.umich.edu"
$de= new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ($domain, $null, $null, $auth)


#clear out mcommunity phone numbers table
$result=Invoke-Sqlcmd -database $dbname -serverinstance $DBServer -outputsqlerrors $true -query "truncate table $tablename"

#for each AEC user, insert phonenumbers into peoplesoft.phonenumbers table in aection
foreach($user in $users){
        $user.uniquename
        $filter = "(&(objectclass=umichperson)(uid=" + $user.uniquename + "))"
        $ds = New-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($de,$filter)
        $ds.PropertiesToLoad.add("*") | out-null
        $ds.PropertiesToLoad.add("telephonenumber") |out-null
        $ds.PropertiesToLoad.add("mobile")|out-null
        $ldapuser = $ds.Findall()

        $ldapuser
        $ldapuser.Properties.telephonenumber
        $ldapuser.Properties.mobile

   if ($ldapuser.properties.telephonenumber -ne $null) {  #must have at least one telephone number
       $uniquename = $ldapuser.Properties.uid
       $phone1 = $ldapuser.properties.telephonenumber[0] -replace ('/','-')
       $phone2 = $ldapuser.properties.telephonenumber[1] -replace ('/','-')
       $mobile = $ldapuser.properties.mobile
           
       $result=Invoke-Sqlcmd -database $dbname -serverinstance $DBServer -outputsqlerrors $true -query "insert into $tablename values('$uniquename','$phone1','$phone2','$mobile')"
   }
   else {  #if user only has a mobile number
       $uniquename = $ldapuser.Properties.uid
       $mobile = $ldapuser.properties.mobile

       $result=Invoke-Sqlcmd -database $dbname -serverinstance $DBServer -outputsqlerrors $true -query "insert into $tablename values('$uniquename','$NULL','$NULL','$mobile')"
   }
}
$sqlConnection.close
```

Answer (score 2):

By SQLPS I presume that you mean a PowerShell job step.

[SQL Server 2012 uses a crippled version of PS](http://www.sqlhammer.com/running-powershell-in-a-sql-agent-job/) that does not have full access to all the cmdlets (in fact it's just PS v2.0), whereas SQL Server 2014 has full PowerShell access allowing you to work with impunity.

As a workaround for your issue you could utilize an Operating System (CmdExec) job step and make a call out to your script, saved as a .PS1 file.